# What is causing this date comparison error?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I've been struggling to understand why this query doesn't work.  All of the partition names for this owner have values in the format 'R_DATE_20170831'.  But the query below always returns an error ORA-01841 (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0.  When I display each date part individually they are all within that range.  My NLS_DATE_FORMAT shows a value 'DD-MON-RR'.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dba_tab_partitions
WHERE table_owner = 'myId' AND
      TO_DATE(SUBSTR(partition_name,INSTR(partition_name,'_',1,2) + 1),'YYYYMMDD') < TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 10;
```

I've also tried putting a TO_DATE with appropriate mask around the Sysdate-10, but still get the error.  Any insight? Thank you!

Comment: The syntax as you have it now is correct. I suspect you are not catching the faulty rows. How do you "display each date part individually"? For example, did you first test to see whether the SUBSTR portion you convert to date is always eight characters? **Also**: Please state your exact Oracle version (including subversion - such as 12.1.0.2.0); there is a new function, VALIDATE_CONVERSION, in Oracle 12.2, which could do quick work of these verifications.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen something similar in SQL Server, caused by the fact that the `WHERE` expressions are not necessarily evaluated in order.  That would mean that other partitions are going through the date arithmetic logic -- and causing the failure.

`CASE` guarantees order of evaluation.  Does this work?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dba_tab_partitions
WHERE table_owner = 'myId' AND
      (CASE WHEN  table_owner = 'myId'
            THEN TO_DATE(SUBSTR(partition_name, INSTR(partition_name, '_', 1, 2) + 1), 'YYYYMMDD')
       END) < TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 10;
```

Or this version:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dba_tab_partitions
WHERE table_owner = 'myId' AND
      (CASE WHEN regexp_like(partition_name, '[^_]*_[^_*]_[0-9]{8}$'
            THEN TO_DATE(SUBSTR(partition_name, INSTR(partition_name, '_', 1, 2) + 1), 'YYYYMMDD')
       END) < TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 10;
```

Comment: I would have moved the `table_owner = 'myId'` part into an inline view, but I like this CASE solution.

Comment: That is indeed a common problem - whenever an optimizer (Oracle or otherwise) thinks that pushing predicates will result in faster execution, you can see this kind of behavior. The OP says that when he checked each date part individually, everything was OK - but that has to be looked into. Anyway, good answer!

Comment: To "display each part separately" I was just taking the two main parts of the where clause and moving them to the select clause to display them.  Visually both selected values were all 9 characters in a DD-MMM-YY format, and many of the first values were clearly < the second value (ex. 31-AUG-17, taken from a partition_name of R_DATE_20170831 and 23-SEP-17 taken from the sysdate-10).    When I run the first "CASE" query above, it runs without error, but returns 0 results.  Again from visual inspection of those WHERE parts it looks like I should be getting lots of results back.

Comment: Btw, I'm using Oracle EE 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit